ggplot: adding regression line and CI when y axis is logged
here is my data:x is input values, y is predicted values using lm() model, upr and lwr are 95% CIs calculated from the lm() model
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(cowplot)
library(ggpmisc)

    fit_line <-dput(fit_line)
structure(list(x = c(0.048, 0.55, 0.44, 0.052, 0.029, 0.09, 0.2, 
0.48, 0.51, 0.11, 1.44, 0.15, 0.4, 1.12, 0.54), y = c(535.247309812533, 
1542.55243882316, 1321.82820736665, 543.273645501861, 497.122215288227, 
619.523834550474, 840.248066006986, 1402.09156425993, 1462.28908192988, 
659.655512997113, 3328.41212969858, 739.91886989039, 1241.56485047337, 
2686.30527455236, 1522.48659959984), lwr = c(-474.582987840204, 
754.520653106387, 576.903888431076, -461.460391144338, -537.324262756609, 
-338.409577605306, -2.1782812716142, 647.785886082738, 696.130234140302, 
-274.914182245542, 1249.20869628597, -150.884187631952, 498.439060263022, 
1155.6674836111, 740.548147246478), upr = c(1545.07760746527, 
2330.58422453993, 2066.75252630222, 1548.00768214806, 1531.56869333306, 
1577.45724670625, 1682.67441328559, 2156.39724243711, 2228.44792971946, 
1594.22520823977, 5407.61556311119, 1630.72192741273, 1984.69064068372, 
4216.94306549362, 2304.4250519532)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15"))

so what i try to plot is line with CIs, byt log y scale.But smth happening:
so first when i do not log scale:
ggplot() +
 # scale_y_log10(breaks = c(10, 100, 1000, 10000),labels = c("10", "100", "1000", "10000")  ) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 1.5),ylim = c(10, 10000)) +
  theme_cowplot() +
  annotation_logticks(sides = "l") +
  geom_ribbon(data = fit_line, aes(x,y,ymin = lwr, ymax = upr), fill = "grey80", alpha = 0.4) 


I don't understand where that black rectangle is coming from?
then when i log the y-scale i loose some CIs:
ggplot() +
  scale_y_log10(breaks = c(10, 100, 1000, 10000),labels = c("10", "100", "1000", "10000")  ) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 1.5),ylim = c(10, 10000)) +
  theme_cowplot() +
  annotation_logticks(sides = "l") +
  geom_ribbon(data = fit_line, aes(x,y,ymin = lwr, ymax = upr), fill = "grey80", alpha = 0.4) 


Can you please help me to figure out what is the issue in my code? or what is happening?

You have negative values in lwr, this is why you lose some intervals. The black rectangular is made of your logticks that applied improperly.

thank you for clarification! but i don't understand: the first grah  is not logged,  why it shows up there? and why not black rectangle on 2nd graph?

In the first plot you are taking log values and plotting them on the linear scale thus compressing the spacing between them. This function should only be used on log10 axis.

So sorry… I don’t think I get it. What log values I take? I take x and y values that are not logged and I comment out the line the transform the y axis to log 10

The annotation_logticks(sides = "l") function should not be use with a linear scale.

got it! thank you for your explanations

annotation_logticks function takes log10 from the original y axis values, which ggplot holds after log10 transformation of the axis with scale_y_log10. If you don't actually do the transformation, the values for logtickes will be very small (1 to 5 in your case). This is why you see that black rectangular, which made of compressed logticks. So, apply annotation_logticks only together with axis log transformation.
As I mentioned in the comments, for the second plot, you lose some intervals because you have negative values in lwr. You need to decide what to do with them. You may want to convert negative values to some small positive number.
geom_ribbon(data = fit_line %>% mutate(lwr = ifelse(lwr < 0, 1, lwr)), 
            aes(x,y,ymin = lwr, ymax = upr), fill = "grey80", alpha = 0.4) 

